# RTL8188CE doesn't connect to any wifi access points

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, thinkpad

I'm using network manager to connect. Also, tryed `iwconfig`. Results are same. I even try to connect to open access point — results are same. More information:

```
Drakmail@thinkpad-x220:~$ lspci  | grep Network | grep -v Ethernet
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)

Drakmail@thinkpad-x220:~$ uname -a
Linux thinkpad-x220 3.1.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 26 02:19:49 UTC 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

Drakmail@thinkpad-x220:~$ dmesg | tail -n 10
[  846.901574] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[  906.812461] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[  966.728810] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[ 1026.639676] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
[ 1030.925574] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
```

At this moment I try to connect to open wifi ap:

```
[ 1031.252403] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:8c:55:fa:ed (try 1/3)
[ 1031.451943] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:8c:55:fa:ed (try 2/3)
[ 1031.651658] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:8c:55:fa:ed (try 3/3)
[ 1031.851354] wlan0: direct probe to 00:24:8c:55:fa:ed timed out
[ 1086.544960] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
```

My distribution:

```
Drakmail@thinkpad-x220:~$ cat /etc/*version
AgiliaLinux release 8.0.0 (Sammy)
```

(Something between Slackware and Archlinux).

Also, I saw that wifi module to often trying to load a firmware file.

Any ideas what it would be?

Answer (score 0):

I am running Fedora 16 on a Toshiba P750 with the same wireless card and a similar problem.

Some points [from this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1873537) seem plausible.

The driver integrated in the linux kernel is not enabling the wireless card to connect with wireless access points especially when there are:

1. several access points with the same name (eg. in airports, universities)
2. access points with blanks and strange characters in their ESSID

A solution that you could perhaps try ([from this thread](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/182885-solved-wifi-struggles-2.html)) is to boot with an alternative kernel. (In the thread they booted with 3.0.0-300 and this solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Ariel! I observed, that with kernel 3.1.2 and 3.1.4 all works fine for me (but after this weird actions: update kernel (to 3.1.2 or to 3.1.4) with plugged ethernet cable, reboot, get DHCP address, try to connect to wifi ap, fail, do rmmod rtl8192ce, after it do modprobe rtl8192ce, wait 10 seconds, try to connect again, success, unplug ethernet cable). When I'll had some free time — I'll try to investigate it.

Comment: I have these two kernels: 3.1.2-1.fc16.x86_64 & 3.1.0-7.fc16.x86_64. Both have problems with multiple-access-point wifi and do fairly okay on single-access point wifi (my home network).